# What's a good memory-efficient text viewer for Linux?

Tags: linux, console, full-text-search, text-editor

I need to browse humongous log files from the command line while connected to a web server.  I don't want to open the file and have the entire contents read into memory, hogging up the server's memory.  I just need to be able to page through and search the log.

I usually use "nano".  Is this one all right with memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need edit functions. [`less`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=less) is sufficient.

Usage:

```
less /path/to/your/logs
```

Use arrow keys or Page up/down to navigate. Type `h` for more information.

Tested memory usage on a 15.31 MB error log:
`nano`: 23576 kB
`less`: 3580 kB

That's a pretty big difference!